# What's the Complexity of this Algorithm? BigO

Tags: big-o

I have the following algorithm:

```
for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++) {
    for (j=i; j<=n-1; j++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (k=i; k<=j; k++) {
            sum = sum + v[k];
        if (sum > max) max = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

The complexity of the first is O(n), the second is n-i, the third is j-i+1.

I know O(n^3) is an upper bound. But what's the true thing we can assume as complexity of this algorithm? Is it O(n^3)?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `O(n^3)` in worst case (when `i`, `j` and `k` are of similar value). It's `O(n)` in best case, when `j` and `k` are 0 or 1:)

Since you have to be prepared for worst case data (and this is the main reason of examining complexity) you should assume `O(n^3)`

Answer (score 2):

I think O(n^3), the limits of the iterations doesnt matter.